# How to Configure Eclipse.ini File to Mirror Shell Script To Enable TLS

Tags: java, eclipse, unix, ssl, jvm

I have a shell script that looks like:

```
cd ~/git/Development/project/target
java -Xmx4096m -Xms1024m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/pki/java/trustStore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=$(cat /home/name/scripts/jks-password) -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/etc/pki/java/server_keystore.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=$(cat /home/name/scripts/server-password) -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -jar api*.jar
```

and when I run that from the terminal it works perfectly fine.

However, for development/testing purposes I want to be able to run my application from within Eclipse. So I updated my `eclipse.ini` file to include:

```
-Xmx4096m 
-Xms1024m 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/etc/pki/java/trustStore.jks"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=$(cat "/home/name/scripts/jks-password")
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="/etc/pki/java/server_keystore.p12"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=$(cat "/home/name/scripts/server-password")
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12 
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

However, when I try to run my application as a Java application inside of Eclipse, I get a SSLHandshakeException, which indicates that it is not picking up my JVM arguments. Can someone help me correctly configure my eclipse.ini file?

Comment: You can't use things like `$(cat ....` in the eclipse.ini - it isn't a shell script and doesn't support that. You must also put just one entry a line so that last line is also wrong.

Comment: So should I just type the passwords directly in the .ini file? And excuse the last part; that was just just a formatting error when I wrote it into StackOverflow (they are on separate lines in the .ini file).

Comment: Note that things you put in the eclipse.ini are only used by Eclipse itself, not programs you run from Eclipse. The 'Run > Run Configuration' entry for the program is where settings for a program go.

Comment: Ah, that's where the discrepancy was for me. I just pasted those same arguments (without the unix commands) into the Run Configuration -> Java Application -> Arguments -> VM arguments and it was able to run the program like normal. Thank you so much!